# Why does a NULL aggregate warning in an SQL query causes the SSIS package to fail?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

An SSIS Package was failing with an error message as below:

> Code: 0xC0202009
>      Source: DFT Populate ImageSummary OLE_SRC ProductImage [1]
>      Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client"  Hresult: 0x00040EDA  Description: "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.".

On investigation, we have found that the message `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` is being returned by a SQL server (2005) query which the SSIS package runs as the source in DFT to insert into a destination table.

```
Select ProductID ,ImageTypeID ,DistinctImageCount ,ImageSize 
from 
    (select a.ProductID ,a.ImageTypeID ,a.DistinctImageCount ,a.ImageSize ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProductID, a.ImageTypeID ORDER BY a.ImageSize) As Ranker 
    from 
        (SELECT TOP 100 Percent spi.ProductID ,sit.ImageTypeID ,CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT spi2.ImageTypeID) as bit) DistinctImageCount ,CAST(spi2.Size as varchar(50)) as ImageSize 
        FROM Stage.ProductImage spi CROSS JOIN Reference.ImageType sit LEFT JOIN Stage.ProductImage spi2 ON spi.ProductID = spi2.ProductID AND sit.ImageTypeID = spi2.ImageTypeID 
        GROUP BY spi.ProductID, sit.ImageTypeID,spi2.Size 
        ORDER BY spi.ProductID, sit.ImageTypeID,spi2.Size
        )a
    )b 
where ranker = 1 
Order by ProductID,ImageTypeID
```

We have resolved the issue by eliminating the warning message from SQL server by modifying the query:

#### From

`CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT spi2.ImageTypeID)as bit) DistinctImageCount`

#### To

`CAST(SUM(DISTINCT ISNULL(spi2.ImageTypeID,0)) as bit) DistinctImageCount`.

However we have few questions as below which we couldn't find an explanation and hoping to get an answer on this forum:

1. Why does a warning from SQL bubbles up to the SSIS package and causes the
   SSIS package to fail?
2. If we run the same package in all other dev and UAT environments
   with the same data set, it works fine. We can see the warning
   showing up in the SQL Server Management Studio, however does not
   cause the SSIS to fail. However the SSIS package in our Production
   environment fails. We are failing to understand the logic? Is there
   any threshold of warnings?

Comment: For #2, that sounds suspiciously like a variance in patch levels between production and your dev & UAT. Can you confirm?

Comment: Unfortunately they are all exactly the same! SQL Server 2005 SP4 CU3 has been applied across the board.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSIS package failure due to the following warning message is a known bug that has been reported by many at Microsoft Connect website.

`Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation`

[Link to the bug report on Connect website.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/483175/failure-because-of-warning-about-null-aggregation)

Microsoft team's last update on the issue:

```
This problem was resolved in SQL Server 2012 RTM (11.00.2100.60 or later).
There is no hotfix available for SQL Server 2005/2008/2008R2.
```

I don't know the cause of the issue and Microsoft team has also closed this bug as not reproducible. One of the workarounds listed on the Connect website is adding the following statement before your query. Please make sure to include the semicolon at the end.

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
```

Read more about [ANSI_WARNINGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are aware of this solution. What I am after is an answer to the two questions from SSIS perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, sql 2008r2. The particular data flow that had the issue had been rock solid for months with no issue. I could not find the null data either.

Verified database property "ANSI Warnings Enabled" was set to False. Added SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; to beginning of query, and it worked. So it appears that this bug does ignore the database wide setting.